# JMeter - WebDriver Sampler - Autofill name by Google Map (Clarification)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Hi Thanks for your prompt responses. I'm currently having the below class and screen capture. Can you please how to written the suitable code? Many Thanks

This is my currently codes but it don't autofill the text.
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@value='']")).sendKeys("57 java");

Class:
`<div class="el-input el-input--mini"><input placeholder="" value="57 Java Rd, North Point, Hong Kong" class="el-input__inner pac-target-input" autocomplete="off"></div>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the codes and work fine as below:

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@value='']")).sendKeys("423 Queen's Road West, Sai Ying Pun, Hong Kong");
sleep(5000);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@value='']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);